# Adding elements to a column layout in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, layout, pysimplegui

I am trying to add elements to a layout while the program is running.
As shown in the code, the layout of the window contains 4 column layouts and I am looking for a way to change the layout of a column while the GUI is active.

```
layout = [[sg.Column(main_layout, element_justification='c', justification='c', 
               key='main_page'),
           sg.Column(analysis_layout, element_justification='c', justification='c', 
               key='analysis_page', visible=False),
           sg.Column(flow_layout, element_justification='c', justification='c', 
               key='flow_page', visible=False),
           sg.Column(settings_layout, element_justification='c', justification='c', 
               key='settings_page', visible=False)]]

window = sg.Window(title="PayOff", layout=layout, element_justification='c', size=(1900, 
             900))
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's no method provided to add element(s) into a row in PySimpleGUI.

Comment: You could make empty Column elements on a row and then add to them later.  "change the layout" is possible by "swapping" the layout as shown in the ecookbook.  It's a vague question so hard to answer.